# Separate source packages for amd64 and x86

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, deb, fmod

I'm trying to package the current stable version of [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org) for Debian. My issue is that there are separate source tarballs for the amd64 and x86 architectures. How to handle this case?

I first tried to create separate fmodex32 and fmodex64 packages which both provide a virtual package called `fmodex` but this approach failed as fmodex-dev should require fmodex in its exact version. Dependencies on specific versions are never satisfied by virtual packages.

Comment: Couldn't you just fake it with two different packages with the same name?

Comment: Or put two different upstream tarballs and have `debian/rules` use one or the other depending on the target architecture?